# How to store network configuration and reload?

Tags: networking

I have an Ubuntu Linux server machine.

It boots up fine and gets it's network configuration up and running perfectly fine.

What I want to do, is somehow grab the network configuration and save it, and somehow reload that exact same network configuration.  Specifically ip address and netmask, router/gateway and any static routes.

The reasons are obscure and probably not so relevant.

Is there a way to do this? To grab an existing network config and re-run it?

UPDATE RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

OK to explain why I have such a strange request:

What I am doing is executing a new operating system from within an existing operating system.  The new operating system needs to implement the exact same network setup - i.e. router/gateway and ip address/netmask.  The network information is not available via DHCP or any other mechanism - it gets injected into the first operating system when it boots.  That means I need to pass the networking information from the first OS into the second OS, from which point I need to instruct the second OS to configure itself with the network information that was passed in.  That's the context, although I suspect that explaining it will confuse the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "grab the network configuration"?  Which parts of the network configuration? Just ip addresses? Also domain name servers? Routing? Firewall?   Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to do? It might help us give you better answers.

Comment: I have added explanation to post.

Comment: how does "it get injected" if not "by DHCP or any other mechanism" ?

Comment: I guess some provisioning machine writes a file onto the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you use NetworkManager (NM) or not. If you use NM (which is the default for Ubuntu), then you can find system wide settings under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. The details for each connection are stored in a separate file. These files can be copied as you like.

If you don't use NM, or you want to configure an interface without NM, then have a look at `/etc/network/interfaces` (see the man page for it, i.e. `man interfaces`). In this file you can define the settings for each interface (by default, only the loopback device `lo` is configured there). You can copy the entire file; if you want only specific parts from it, then a bit of text-processing-fu is required.

N.B. The difference is that using NM you can define more than one setting per interface, from which the user can select a suitable one. Using `/etc/network/interfaces` allows you to define only one setting per interface; if you need flixibility here, you need to write a suitable script and store it in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`